# How do Microservices enable CI/CD

Tags: continuous-integration, microservices, continuous-deployment

I've been reading a lot of articles that state microservices enable CI/CD. However, the articles don't explain how or why this is the case. It seems that you could continuously deploy a monolith as well once all of its automated tests pass.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many aspects of this.

> It seems that you could continuously deploy a monolith as well once all of its automated tests pass.

A monolith is typically *stateful*, e.g. sessions is used for short lived user state. Where as modern microservice architecture typically follows [The Twelve Factor App](https://12factor.net/) principles and are typically deployed on e.g. Kubernetes or other cloud environment. Apps following the Twelve Factor App principles and apps on Kubernetes are *stateless*, e.g. all user state most be handled outside the app. See https://12factor.net/processes

With stateless apps, it is much easier to scale-out to more instances e.g. 5 instances for an app and it is also easy to scale down to fewer instance, e.g. 2 instances.

When the app is *stateless* and runs in multiple instances - doing a "rolling deployment" e.g. updating one instance at the time, form version1 to version2 is an easy process and built-in functionality in Kubernetes.

With all the above features in-place, it is now much easier to implement Continuous Deployment compared to how it was with large stateful monolithic apps.